# Need to skip the HomeDirectory permission check on remote machine for the ssh client .How to set StrictModes off for a specific host in ssh client?

Tags: ssh, unix, shell, passwords, ssh-keys

I am trying to connect to a remote machine over ssh in a passwordless manner using ssh-keys .But it is failing to connect without password due to the permission on the remote server home folder (777) . When I changes the permission to (755) on remote machine it works perfectly .

I am aware that the ssh requires the permission on the remote server home folder as not writable by others/group ( ie less than 777 obviously) .

But this remote server that I am connecting requires the permission to be kept as 777 as it is needed for some other work . So I was trying to add the below block in **/etc/ssh/ssh_config**

```
> Host remote_machine
        HostName <remote_ip>
        User <username>
        StrictModes no
```

But when i try to connect over it fails by saying :

```
 bash-4.1# ssh remote_machine
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 64: **Bad configuration option: StrictModes**
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

So how can I turn off the Home folder permission check for a specific host for the ssh connection when doing the passwordless connectivity using ssh-keys.

I tried checking in a lot off online sites, but no progress yet . Any help on this regard is highly appreciated .

Comment: What possible reason is there to *need* a home directory to be writable by *all* other users on the machine? That sounds very broken and insecure to me, and `sshd` is right to complain about it.

Answer (score 1):

The checks are performed **by the server.** `ssh` (the client) absolutely doesn't care, and in fact has no way of knowing those permissions anyway.

Therefore, `StrictModes no` also needs to be specified on the *server's* `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: How can I specify the "StrictModes no" specific for a client ?

Answer (score 1):

If you administer this remote server, then you can configure sshd to look elsewhere for the authorized_keys of a login account:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/authorized_keys/%u
```